# After I Had To Force Terminal Restart, I Can't Run "rails s" command again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I was using the terminal as always, when it froze. I had to restart the VM (Ubuntu x64) and load it again. But after restarting, I could not use the command `rails s` again, and it logged this on the terminal:
http://pastebin.com/raw/v7tfGWBk

Ps: I already tried to run bundle install/update and look for doubled ruby processes on System Monitor

Ps2: I can still use other commands such as `rails new test12`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Restore previous version of openssl and try

```
gem uninstall openssl -v 2.0.3

gem install openssl -v 2.0.2
```

Comment: i am using rbenv and not rvm

Comment: my bad. Re-installing openssl and ruby will help I guess.

Comment: do you have a command for that , im totally a newbie

Comment: delete openssl: `sudo apt-get purge openssl`, install openssl: `sudo apt-get install openssl` and install ruby: `rbenv install 2.4`

Comment: I manage to reinstall openssl ( purge and then install ) and everything, but `rails s` continue not working

Comment: Did you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same error, maybe something wrong with Cipher, do you know what it it? And I forgot to say that the command `rbenv install 2.4` returned an error: http://i.imgur.com/n29MuVx.jpg

Comment: Updated the answer, can you try that?

Comment: It worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check if puma (or server that you are using) is still running using:

```
ps aux | grep puma
```

You will obtain something like this:

[image]

The process in this case for puma server is 1142 so you have to kill it:

```
kill -9 1142
```

After that you should be able to start rails server again.

Comment: It logs

        "redmanb+  2050  0.0  0.0  21292   964 pts/17   S+   12:59   0:00 grep --color=auto puma"

Comment: And when i try to kill process 2050 it says that there are no processes with this id

Comment: could you please take a screenshot in order to help you?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nfXsKrB.jpg

Comment: cool, there's no puma server running in your system right now the line that you are seeing is the grep itself. So if you are using puma there's no server running in background.Run rails s and upload a screenshot please

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/S2KTArS.jpg  
(the entire log can be seen here http://pastebin.com/raw/v7tfGWBk )

Comment: could you please try to run it using 2.3 ruby version, please

Comment: how i am going to do this? I am not using rvm

Comment: which ruby version manager are you using?

Comment: rbenv 1.1.0-2-g4f8925a | ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux] | Rails 5.0.1

Comment: install 2.3.0 version and try again rbenv install 2.3.0